# How do you most correctly use the word "than"? (SAT writing question)

Tags: grammar

The Piraha people of Brazil communicate(A) almost as much by singing, whistling, and(B) humming than(C) they do(D) by pronouncing consonants and vowels. No error(E)

I had chosen E, no error, but the correct answer is c, than. Why is C the right answer?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This question probably belongs on http://ell.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Homework questions are off-topic on ELU.

Comment: Okay, I apologize about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Than* should be *as*: *as much X as Y* is the idiom. *More X than Y* and *less X than Y*, though.